# Serialization of objects (C#)

Tags: c#, serialization

I am trying to understand serialization and the way data is passed between the client and server, but I am still not clear.

Is converting objects to JSON strings (or XML/something else) what serialization actually stands for? If not, what is the link between the two?

(the language I am using to learn is c#, if it matters)

Thanks!

Comment: If you Google *serialization*, this is literally the first link that comes up, did you even try to look yourself? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/serialization/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would define serialization more broadly; as the means to which an object (usually only represented by memory) is translated into an *easily transferrable* format. Those formats include:

- JSON
- XML
- Binary
- FlatBuffer
- ProtoBuf

And many, many others.

Deserialization is then the means by which that format is translated *back* into an object in memory.